# Magento2 API : update product data not assign to All store view

Tags: magento2, product, api, multistore

> ***API call : /V1/products/{sku}***
>
> I'm Updating product by API.
>
> In which I'm passing website ids 0,1,2.
>
> It will update data only in stores, not to All store View.
>
> I don't want it to update storewise,it should update Globally to all
>   stores.

***How can I achieve this?***

> ***UPDATE***
>
> I want to get Product All Store View and Store wise, also want the
>   same update product store wise and all store view. How can I achieve
>   it by API?
>
> I want same for categories

**Magento: 2.2.2**

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use a different endpoint to update all store views.
This will update all store views:

```
/all/V1/products/{sku}
```

However, somthing like the following will only update default store view

```
/default/V1/products/{sku}
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this end point of API to achieve

/all/V1/products/{sku}